# Is it considered bad practice to a new generate presigned URL per HTTP request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I've been looking through the presigned URL documentation, and have not encountered much information about how often I can generate these presigned URLs. Judging by the length of the identifier, I'm thinking it's probably collision-safe to generate a new one for every URL request.

I think a more conventional method is to run a cron job to generate a new one and store it in a record DB with the file key, and this would be perfectly doable, but I was wondering if I could skip this step and just generate it on the fly.

Comment: I have a couple of services which produce thousands of presigned urls per second. You're not supposed to store presigned urls: they should be treated as short lived tokens which allow unauthenticated users to temporarily access data items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to have a presigned url without expiry time and the maximum expiry time you can set is 1 week. These URLs are designed to be temporary to allow users to access your S3 bucket, either for READ the object or WRITE an Object (or update an existing object).

So as an answer, it is not a bad practice to generate a new presigned URL per request since its nature to be temporary.

Comment: But how computationally expensive is it to generate one? i.e. if i'm querying hundreds of records and presign a url for each single one of them on every request, is there going to be a considerable overhead in that usecase or is it still okay to generate a new presigned url for every request?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way, as told to me by a recent object storage provider, is that you use a cdn in front of the request. In this way, your users fetch the file using a endpoint that handles the fetching from the provider (either your own or a paid service).

In our case, we set up a location that, on receipt, fetches the object from the storage using the secret/key/etc necessary, and returns the data as the response content.

Something like:

**/uploads/index.php**

```php
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

// The url is of the form: https://the.fqdn.com/uploads?id=TheObjectKey
$key = $_GET['id'] ?? null; // if needed, lookup the necessary details such as bucket/region/etc for the given key

$region = 'YOUR-REGION';
$s3Key = 'YOUR-KEY';
$s3Secret = 'YOUR-SECRET';
$url = 'YOUR-ENDPOINT-URL';
$bucket = 'YOUR-S3-BUCKET';

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => $region,
    'endpoint'    => $url,
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $s3Key,
        'secret' => $s3Secret,
    ],
]);

// Get the object from the bucket
$result = $s3->getObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
]);

// Set appropriate headers
header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
header('Content-Disposition: inline');
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$key\"");
// Output the file content
echo $result['Body'];
?>
```

Be sure to add whatever is necessary for validation of authorization.